# Integrating out a Lagrange multiplies field enforcing a differential form to be "$2\pi$-integral periodic"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry, topological-field-theory

In the appendix A (page: 26-27) of the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0108152 by Juan Maldacena, Gregory Moore and Nathan Seiberg, the author writes the following "action"
$$e^{-i\int_{X_D}\left[{1 \over 2}\kappa_1(B_{p+1}+kA_{p+1})\wedge * (B_{p+1}+kA_{p+1}) +{1 \over 2} \kappa_2 dA_{p+1} \wedge * dA_{p+1} +{1 \over {2\pi}} B_{p+1}\wedge d\lambda_{D-p-2}\right]}~.$$
It is said that the field strengths of the field $\lambda_{D-p-2}$ has "$2\pi$ integral periods". Now I dont know what does it mean to say that a differential form has a "$2\pi$ integral periods". I **assumed** that it means $\int d\lambda_{D-p-2} =2 \pi Z$.
Then the authors say that **"Integrating out $\lambda_{D−p−2}$ forces $B_{p+1}$ to be closed with (2π)-integral periods"**. Again, I assume that this means $\int B_{p+1}=2 \pi Z$. My question is the following:

I understand that integrating out $\lambda_{D-p-2}$ enforces $dB_{p+1}=0$. But **how does it imply impliy that "$B_{p+1}$ has $2\pi$-integral period"?**